# Windows10(1803) + WSL + Ubuntu16.04 + Docker環境で作成したコンテナにdocker execコマンドで入れない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wsl

Windows10(1803) + WSL + Ubuntu16.04 + Docker環境にて、
作成したDockerコンテナにdocker execコマンドで入ろうとすると
エラーが発生して入れない現象が発生しています。

環境や行いたいこと、発生した現象については下記の通りです。

●環境
 OS: Windows10(Build1803)
 その他: WSL + Ubuntu16.04 + Docker(version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e)

●行いたいこと
 上記環境にて作成したDockerコンテナにdocker execコマンドで入って操作したい。

●何が問題なのか
  作成したDockerコンテナ(名前はhoge)を起動し、

```
docker exec -it hoge /bin/bash
```

を実行してコンテナに入ろうとすると

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "could not create session key: function not implemented"
```

と、エラーメッセージが表示され、入ることができない。

以上、解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

**2018/12/04追記**
使用したDockerイメージは下記内容のDockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
```

を元に

```
docker build ./ -t test-image
```

コマンドで作成したものです。
(カレントディレクトリを指定していますが、
ディレクトリ内は上記のDockerfileしか存在していない状態です。)

上記のtest-imageを作成した後に

```
docker run --name hoge -itd test-image /bin/bash
```

コマンドでコンテナを作成し、

```
docker exec -it hoge /bin/bash
```

を実行すると、本文に記述したエラーメッセージが表示されてコンテナに入ることができません。

Comment: WSL Ubuntu は Microsoft Store からインストールされたものでしょうか？

Comment: はい、Microsoft Storeからインストールしたものです。

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/161703 (参考: [マルチポストについて](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110))

Comment: Koki Nakamura さん、そうでしたら、このエラーだけだと原因を特定しにくいので、公開できる範囲でどういう Docker イメージなのか書いていただかないと難しいかもしれません。

Comment: マルチポストについては理解しています。こちらで解決しましたら、teratailの質問にも情報を展開し、Closeする予定です。

Comment: マルチポストが問題となる原因のひとつはそれぞれのサイトの回答者が情報を共有できないことにあるので、マルチポストしていること自体を質問文に書いて回答者に知らせて欲しいです。また英語版 Stack Overflow においてはクロスポストするにしてもよく考えて欲しいと言われています (参考: [Cross-posting between localized Stack Overflow versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270047/5989200))。お手数ですが回答者の手間を減らすためによろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、認識不足でした。マルチポストおよびクロスポストについては、削除します。

Comment: Dockerイメージ等についての情報を追記しました。2018/12/04追記以下をご確認ください。

Comment: Docker on WSL はまだまだ対応途中という感じがあってどこが原因なのか上手く掴めませんが、[この reddit の投稿](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/8cvr27/docker_is_running_natively_on_wsl/e4qjuiq/)に "`docker exec` doesn't work by default. Had to add `--no-new-keyring` to `docker-runc` command lines when necessary" と書かれているのを見つけました。私の Windows と Koki さんの Windows で環境が違うので手元では再現できていないのですが、もしかすると一次的な回避策として参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 情報をいただき、ありがとうございます。
いただいた情報に加え https://qiita.com/Arturias/items/f73e71cfce64e74fd8be や
 https://qiita.com/sysvirt/items/d362dd26eeb30c5250aa を元に
[sudo docker-runc run --no-new-keyring hoge]
を実行してみたところ、
「container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:111: setting rootfs as readonly caused \\\"device or resource busy\\\"\""」
というエラーメッセージが表示されて実行できませんでした。
現状では行いたいことが行えなさそうなので、docker attachコマンドを使用することにします。